# Spring security applying filters to specified endpoint and HttpMethod

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've been trying to add a custom filter in specific operations on a given rest controller.
In my configuration I'm trying to add this filter to only specific HttpMethods like : POST,DELETE, PATCH.
With this I wanted to set a configuration that would allow all GET operations to be ignored by the filter, but it seems that the filter is always trying to authenticate GET operations.
This is my base configure method on my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
               .formLogin().disable()
               .csrf().disable()
               .logout().disable()
               .addFilter(new CustomSecurityFilter(authenticationManager()))
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/v1/call/{id}").hasAnyRole("ADMIN,EDITOR")
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/v1/call/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN,EDITOR")
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/v1/call/{id}/disable").hasAnyRole("ADMIN,EDITOR")
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/call").hasAnyRole("ADMIN,EDITOR");
   }
```

Is there another way to set the filter to ignore GET operations? In this case if the match is for "/v1/call/{id}"

Answer (score 0):

You can add `antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/call/{id}").permitAll()` to allow your GET requests to pass.